# Python select.select leaking threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have a program that maintains a connection to a server with a periodic heartbeat. Every once in a while, the server stops responding to heartbeats and I have to reconnect. I implemented this with a timer that, if no response is heard after n seconds, will call reconnect. Every time this happens, I leak a thread and over time I eventually run out of threads.

Now, simplifying massively for an easy repro, this illlustrates how reconnecting after a delay and how always causes an increase in threads. **How can I kill the old threads/sockets/selects** (which may be waiting on a recv)?

```
import socket
import select
import threading

class Connection():

    def tick(self):
        print(threading.active_count()) # this increases every 1s!
        # ... certain conditions not met / it's been too long, then:
        self.reconnect()

    def reconnect(self):
        self.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        self.socket.close()
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.connect((IP, TCP_PORT))
        self.timer = threading.Timer(1, self.tick)
        self.timer.start()
        r,_,_ = select.select([self.socket], [], [])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Connection().connect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, it's not `select()` that leaks any threads. Let's assume the `select()` doesn't return, i.e it blocks forever.

In that case

- `.tick()` is called from the timer thread.
- `.tick()` calls `.reconnect()` within the timer thread.
- `.reconnect()` closes the existing socket. This causes the active `select()` call to fail with `IOError` "Bad file descriptor" (which is also why you should really fix your code).
- `.reconnect()` tries to cancel the current timer. 
  This does nothing, since the timer already triggered (we are currently inside the timer function!).
- `.reconnect()` calls `.connect()` and that one establishes a new timer and here we go again.

So the question is: Where does this mode of operation hang on to the existing timer object? Well, all your timer threads get terminated by an `IOError` from the `select()` call. This stores a per-thread reference of the exception.

My guess is that this prevents the reference counted cleanup in CPython to trigger and hence the timer thread will only be cleaned up during garbage collection. This is unreliable, since there is no guarantee that the timer thread is ever cleaned up in time.

If you add `import gc; gc.collect()` at the start of `.connect()`, the problem (seems to) goes away. But yeah, that's a non-solution.

Why don't you use the `timeout` parameter to [`select()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) to achieve a similar result without having to use a timer thread?

```
r = []
while not r:
    if self.socket:
        self.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        self.socket.close()

    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.socket.connect((IP, TCP_PORT))
    # select returns empty lists on timeout
    r, _, _ = select.select([self.socket], [], [], 1)
```

Don't forget to set `self.socket = None` in `Connection.__init__()` for this to work.